# Plesk Linux ASP.NET Core ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: c#, asp.net, linux, asp.net-core, plesk

I set up a Basic Asp.Net Core Website on my CentOS 7 Server. If i run it with localhost:5001 everything works fine and the site opens.

If i Go Over my Domain in Plesk i get a ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED HTPP 307.

[Here a Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtJIO.png)

I Set up The Apache  Reverse Proxy for The Domain in Plesk under The Apache and Nginx Settings Page like this:

ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:5000/

I think something is wrong with  The redirect , because on localhost it works fine.

Can someone help me please?

Comment: In the Startup.cs i deleted app.UseHttpsRedirection(); and now it works fine :D.

Comment: Post your finding as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Startup.cs i deleted app.UseHttpsRedirection(); and now it works fine

Answer (score 0):

I shared my anwser. I'm using ASP .NET Core Web API on CentOS7 (VirtualBox virtual machine) and access from real machine (Windows 10 Chrome)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70344781/9347676