# ASP Net Core Linux ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: linux, nginx, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, digital-ocean

I'm testing net core app deployment to a Digitalocean droplet running Ubuntu 18.04 and Nginx 1.14. For testing, I'm using the templates available from 'dotnet new'.

The 
**dotnet new web**
and 
**dotnet new mvc**
apps work fine. I'm able to reach them from my browser. I'm having issues with the **dotnet new webapi** app. However I try to reach it, I end up with a ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED response.

Short version of what I've done to setup my droplet:

> wget -q
>   https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/18.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb
>
> sudo dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb
>
> sudo add-apt-repository universe
>
> sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install
>   dotnet-sdk-2.2
>
> sudo apt install nginx sudo ufw allow 'Nginx HTTP'

/etc/nginx/sites-available/default content:

```
server {
 listen 80;
 location / {
 proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000; #also tried localhost:5000
 proxy_http_version 1.1;
 proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
 proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
 proxy_set_header Host $host;
 proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
 }
}
```

Results from curl (ip address intentionally derped)

> curl -I -X GET http://123.123.123.123/api/values

```
HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect
Server: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
Date: Sun, 19 May 2019 00:32:21 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://123.123.123.123:5001/api/values
```

My Nginx log gives me this error, which I've Googled to no avail:

```
2019/05/19 00:03:06 [error] 3632#3632: *4 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 12.123.12.123, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/", host: "123.123.123.117"
```

In response to @Oliver's question, here's the output of netstat -ntlp

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3527/nginx: master
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      605/systemd-resolve
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      946/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      946/sshd
```

Any suggestions as to what I might be overlooking?

Thanks!

Comment: The Web API template enforced HTTPS, so the redirection leads the browser to port 5001. However, your nginx configuration does not expose the HTTPS service at port 5001. That explains exactly why ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED happened. You can edit the test project and remove its HTTPS redirection.

Comment: What's the output of `netstat -nltp`?

Comment: @Oliver I updated the question to include netstat -nltp output, thanks! Looking into removing the HTTPS redirection, thanks for that @ Lex Li

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The response from the server explains the cause. The `GET` request to `http://127.0.0.1:5000` is redirected to `https://123.123.123.123:5001/api/values`, it's because the HTTPS redirection is active.

Solution: Open the `Startup.cs` file. Find the following line in the `public void Configure(...)` method and comment it out:

```cs
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
```

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio) you can read more about it.

Comment: Bingo, was just about to update the post that I got it working doing just that. Thank you VERY much!

Answer (score 0):

I'm in ASP .NET Core Web API, this changes worked for me

Some changes in /Program.cs. Just replace IHostBuilder to IWebHostBuilder and add UseUrls

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseUrls("http://0.0.0.0:5000")
        .UseStartup<Startup>();
```